# How to calculate the time elapsed after a button is released?

Tags: android, time

I am attempting to make a simple Morse code translator. I can calculate how long the user has held down a button in order to make a dot or a dash but i am having trouble calculating the time that has elapsed since the user has released the button - the time elapsed will allow me to figure out if it is a new letter/word by timing the space between symbols.

```
 public void btnPressed(View view)
   {
        button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                lastDown = System.currentTimeMillis();

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                lastDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastDown;

                //Timer starts when the button is released.
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    //This is where attempt to calculate the elapsed time.
    stop = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
```

It does return a time - the problem is that the elapsed time is only a few milliseconds long. Is there a simpler way to go about this?

Comment: are you setting the onTouchListener after the button has been pressed? Try setting it in the onCreate method. You can then do your logic after the `lastDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastDown;` line.

Comment: It seems that was the problem. I suspected i had some sort of design problem but could not figure out what it was exactly. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put following code in `onCreate` instead of `btnPressed`

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                lastDown = System.currentTimeMillis();

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                lastDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastDown;

                //Timer starts when the button is released.
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            }
            return false;
        }
```

what happening in your code is your `touchListner` works only after you click your button. putting it in `onCreate` will make it work all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have confused yourself how to go about solving this problem.
It appears that within your buttons `onTouch` handler you have set it a new handler. This is a complex error prone path to go down.

The simple way is to just have one `onTouch` callback.

This one records both the time the button was down, and up.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // we have pressed, record the time
        pressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // check how long it has been since last release
        timeSinceLastRelease = System.currentTimeMillis() - releaseTime;

    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // we have released, record the time
        releaseTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // check how long it has been since last press
        timeSinceLastPress = System.currentTimeMillis() - pressTime;           
    }
    return false;
}
```